# std::ifstream not reading in after switching text editors from notepad++ to sublime text 2 for using the file it's reading in?

Tags: c++, debugging, file-io

I read some data for my application from file, and it recently stopped working.  I feel like the time when it stopped working corresponds to when I switched from Notepad++ to Sublime Text 2...  Anyway, here is my code to read in the data:

```
    std::ifstream stream;
    stream.open("parsing_model.txt");

    char ignore_char;
    std::string model_class;
    int parsing_model;
    while (stream >> model_class >> ignore_char >> parsing_model)
    {
        // snip
        // doesn't even make it into a single run of this while loop.
    }
```

My data is organized as

```
Item1, 12
Item2, 4
foo, 42
bar, 1
```

Is it something in the text encoding?  How can I make my code robust against this and solve my problem?  This code absolutely worked for months up until recently.  Thanks

Comment: I'm quite sure the code doesn't do what you think it does: http://liveworkspace.org/code/f3366236f0fa758f004a80d7e791b989

Comment: @rubenvb Huh. Interesting.  The code has worked with this setup for months, though.  Could it be that istringstream and ifstream have slightly different setups?  Cool tool, by the way

Comment: they do not differ in this respect I believe. As to why the file reading is failing, I really have no clue.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check to see if the stream is in a good state before using it.

```
stream.open("parsing_model.txt");
if (stream.good()) {
    //... read the stream
} else {
    std::cerr << "failed to open input file\n";
}
```

If there is a failure, make sure the current working directory is the same location as where you have saved the input file. It seems you are running on windows, so you should be able to use this command to view your current directory.

```
system("dir & pause");
```